# How to get full address from Google maps api - Places?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get a full address from Google maps autocomplete and it doesn't work. see my code and my console

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = [
    'delivery-street',
    'delivery-suburb',
    'delivery-postcode',
    'delivery-city',
    'delivery-country'
];

window.initAutocomplete = function() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
    // location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
        /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
        {types: ['geocode']});

    // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
    // fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    console.log(place);
    for (var component in componentForm) {
        document.getElementById(componentForm[component]).value = '';
        document.getElementById(componentForm[component]).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    document.getElementById('delivery-street').value = findAttr(place, ['street_number']) + ' ' + findAttr(place, ['route']);
    document.getElementById('delivery-suburb').value = findAttr(place, ['sublocality_level_1', 'locality']);
    document.getElementById('delivery-postcode').value = findAttr(place, ['postal_code']);
    document.getElementById('delivery-city').value = findAttr(place, ['administrative_area_level_1', 'route']);
    document.getElementById('delivery-country').value = findAttr(place, ['country']);
}

function findAttr(place, findType) {
    var response = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < findType.length; j++) {

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if(addressType === findType[j]){
                response.push(place.address_components[i].long_name);
            }
        }

    }
    return response.join(', ')
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
window.geolocate = function () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geolocation = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                center: geolocation,
                radius: position.coords.accuracy
            });
            autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
        });
    }
}
```

So, I put for example "2/89 Union St, New Brighton, Christchurch, New Zealand" and this is the result in my console

```
address_components: Array(7)
0: {long_name: "89", short_name: "89", types: Array(1)}
1: {long_name: "Union Street", short_name: "Union St", types: Array(1)}
2: {long_name: "New Brighton", short_name: "New Brighton", types: Array(3)}
3: {long_name: "Christchurch", short_name: "Christchurch", types: Array(2)}
4: {long_name: "Canterbury", short_name: "Canterbury", types: Array(2)}
5: {long_name: "New Zealand", short_name: "NZ", types: Array(2)}
6: {long_name: "8061", short_name: "8061", types: Array(1)}
```

In the documentation say

The Autocomplete constructor takes two arguments:

- geocode instructs the Places service to return only geocoding
  results, rather than business results.
- address instructs the Places service to return only geocoding results
  with a precise address.

I've tried to use 'address' and nothing change

- Any idea of how to get the number of the flat/unit/apartment?

Comment: The [`formatted_address`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.formatted_address) of the place doesn't work for you?

Comment: I type "2/89 Union St, New Brighton, Christchurch, New Zealand" and it returns ->
formatted_address: "89 Union St, New Brighton, Christchurch 8061, New Zealand"

Comment: That seems like a data problem in Google's places database.  Is the problem that you don't get the text that the user selected?.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem because I need to send stuff to that address! :/ I fixed that by copying the first part of the string in my search input but It's not the best solution, actually is not a solution, just a hack.

Comment: Can you use the value of the `<input>` with id="autocomplete" (when the autocomplete `place_changed` event fires)?

Comment: This has been reported in Google's Issutracker : https://issuetracker.google.com/35830389

You can star this issue to get updates.

Comment: Thanks, mate I'll have a look!!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and ended up just creating a function to build the address I need. This works great for US. I'm not sure about UK...

```
getAddressFromComponents(geo: any) {
    const streetNumber = geo.find( g => g.types.find( t => t === 'street_number') ).long_name;
    const streetName = geo.find( g => g.types.find( t => t === 'route' )).long_name;
    const cityName = geo.find( g => g.types.find( t => t === 'locality') && g.types.find( t => t === 'political' )).long_name;
    const stateName = geo.find( g => g.types.find( t => t === 'administrative_area_level_1') && g.types.find( t => t === 'political' ))
      .long_name;
    const countryName = geo.find( g => g.types.find( t => t === 'country') && g.types.find( t => t === 'political' )).long_name;
    const zip = geo.find( g => g.types.find( t => t === 'postal_code' )).long_name;

    return {
      address: `${streetNumber} ${streetName}`,
      city: cityName,
      state: stateName,
      country: countryName,
      postalCode: zip
    };
  }
```

Usage

`const address = this.getAddressFromComponents( _geoResponse[ 0 ].address_components );`

For what it's worth, we will be switching to Algolia Places as it's easier to use:

https://community.algolia.com/places/

Comment: Yeah but I need it around the world! :/

Comment: I would imagine that most of the info is still correct. I'd give that logic a try with a couple UK addresses. It might work, I'm just saying I haven't tested with any other country outside the US. Worst case scenario, you'll have to interrogate that geo object a little further to capture the properties you're after.